# How to update user role without logout

Tags: users, woocommerce-offtopic, user-roles, capabilities

I am working on a wordpress project with the following plugins :

- Woocommerce
- Woocommerce product vendors
- WP Job Manager
- Wp Job Manager products

I am trying to **upgrade the user role** after adding a job, so the user can access the wp-admin and edit his own product.

Now the user can be upgraded to Manage his Vendor dashboard but the problem that the first time he adds a Job he must login/logout in order to refresh his roles and be able to access the Dashboard.

Here what I tried :

```
        $current_user = wp_get_current_user();

        //Code 1 : 
        $user_id = wp_update_user( array( 'ID' => $current_user->ID, 'role' => 'wc_product_vendors_manager_vendor' ) );

        //Code 2 : 
        $user = new WP_User( $current_user->ID );
        $user->remove_role( 'customer' );
        $user->set_role( 'wc_product_vendors_manager_vendor' );

        //Code 3 : ( this will make the user with 2 roles )
        $current_user->add_role( 'wc_product_vendors_manager_vendor' );
```

Is it possible to achieve this by deleting the **wp_cache_delete** ... does anyone knows a good solution to upgrade user roles without login/logout ?

Thank you for you help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are on the right track, `wp_cache_delete` was what finally helped me get an auto-signup with auto-login plugin working... I have this from there:

```
wp_cache_delete($current_user->ID, 'users');
wp_cache_delete($current_user->user_login, 'userlogins');
```

Then see what roles you get after that with:

```
$current_user = wp_get_current_user();
```

Comment: It works but I got some security issue, for some reason the user got some access to the hole page in the administration ( he can see all the vendors products instead of only his own product ) so for now I just changed the hole logic instead of updating the user role, I am trying to add the role when he first signup, so when he just login he will got the right roles already. Thanks for your help.

Comment: ok that is a problem, if you want to keep testing, I'd suggest adding the code from @Shane's answer to after the cache delete code to try logging the user in again properly.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried logging in the user after your changes?

Such as:

```
 wp_set_current_user( $current_user->ID, $current_user->user_login );

 wp_set_auth_cookie( $current_user->ID );

 do_action( 'wp_login', $current_user->user_login );
```

Comment: Yep I just tried this and it throws some errors from the theme and the plugin 

Warning: Missing argument 2 for WC_Product_Vendors_Authentication::vendor_login_successful() ....


 ( Argument 2 is the user login ...)